# PHP echo and redirect

Tags: php, redirect, echo

```
<?php
$dateiname = 'daten.txt';
$inhalt =$_POST['vorname'].' '.$_POST['nachname']."; ".$_POST['abteilung'].";".$_POST['strecke']."; ".$_POST['groesse'].' ; '.$_POST['tag'].'.'.$_POST['monat'].'.'.$_POST['jahr'].PHP_EOL."";
echo "Sie haben folgende Angaben gemacht:<br>";
echo "Name: $_POST[vorname] $_POST[nachname]
<br>Abteilung: $_POST[abteilung]
<br>Geburtsdatum: $_POST[tag].$_POST[monat].$_POST[jahr]
<br>Strecke: $_POST[strecke]
<br>Groesse: $_POST[groesse]<br> ";
echo "Vielen Dank!";
$handle = @fopen($dateiname, "ab+");
fwrite($handle, $inhalt);
fclose ($handle);
if (file_exists($dateiname) == true) {
@chmod ($dateiname, 0757);
}
sleep(10);
header("location: http://google.com");
?>
```

I try to do a php echo and then redirect after 10secs. But with this code, php echo is not displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're sleeping in the code that **generates** the html for the page, not in the **browser** that displays it to the end user...

Look to pause before redirecting in the browser using a meta refresh. generate html that contains something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.somewhere.com/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Redirecting in 3 seconds...</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$dateiname = 'daten.txt';
$inhalt =$_POST['vorname'].' '.$_POST['nachname']."; ".$_POST['abteilung'].";".$_POST['strecke']."; ".$_POST['groesse'].' ; '.$_POST['tag'].'.'.$_POST['monat'].'.'.$_POST['jahr'].PHP_EOL."";

echo '<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://www.google.com/" />
    </head>
    <body>';

echo "Sie haben folgende Angaben gemacht:<br>";
echo "Name: $_POST[vorname] $_POST[nachname]
<br>Abteilung: $_POST[abteilung]
<br>Geburtsdatum: $_POST[tag].$_POST[monat].$_POST[jahr]
<br>Strecke: $_POST[strecke]
<br>Groesse: $_POST[groesse]<br> ";
echo "Vielen Dank!";
$handle = @fopen($dateiname, "ab+");
fwrite($handle, $inhalt);
fclose ($handle);
if (file_exists($dateiname) == true) {
@chmod ($dateiname, 0757);
}

echo '</body></html>';
```

Comment: So, i've got an input form and this input form is handled by a php. Is there a way to 'embed' this php into an HTML?

Comment: This isn't PHP, this is HTML markup: you can use PHP to generate this HTMl markup...

Comment: ... but if you put a timed redirect on a page that contains a form, you'll get a lot of annoyed users who've partly completed filling in the form suddenly being redirected

Comment: Is it possible to grab the PHP echo to display it on a html page?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking: it's your PHP code that is __generating__ the HTML markup, it can echo whatever you want it to echo

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect users from php AFTER you sent to the user some data.
However you can achieve this by using javascript on your page:

```
<script>
     setTimeout(function(){
          windows.location = "next_page.html";
     }, 10000);
</script>
```

10000ms = 10 sec

Comment: JS will be disabled, and boom, fail... Consider using `meta` instead, read Mark's answer

Comment: Yes, I agree with you :). However, not in all occasions is possible to change the page's `meta`s (for ie. if you have access only to the contents of a website, but you can't change the template). Thegesuser didn't specify all the context, so I posted this alternative.

Comment: Makes sense :) though he will have to feed the script in the template as well.. though +1

Comment: Could also be done via the `body onload`: `<body onload="timer=setTimeout(function(){ window.location='http://www.google.com';}, 3000)">`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side programming language. Once it has been sent to the client, it can no longer update the page, and it returns the whole page generated as an HTML page.
it get a request and generates the response as HMTL and sends it to the client(in this case browser), `sleep(10)`, stops `PHP` script 
for 10 seconds **before** generating the response.
It means it Does not echoes anything before finishing the request.

Answer (score 1):

I did it very similar to @Mark Baker.  Except for using the `$var` instead of the `$_POST['name']`

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "me@email.com";
$subject = "My Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Son of a     biscuit, something went wrong!");
echo '<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=http://www.mywebsite.com/" />

</head>
<body>
   <div>';
     echo "<h1>Thank you for the message: </h1><br>";
     echo "Name: $name <br>
           Email:  $email <br>
           Message: $message";
     echo '</div></body></html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant set header after echo statement.

echo sends header itself so another header is not sent again.